# Kadane's algorithm, maximum summation of consecutive elements

Tags: python, algorithm, list, indexing

How can I keep track of the starting index of the maximum continuous sum problem?

`index_pairs[]` are the starting index `[0]` and the ending index `[1]` of the max cont. sum.

I can always find the last index of the maximum continuous
summation, but my starting index, `index_pairs[0]` will return
the incorrect index if there is a larger number after the maxsum.

My train of thought: In order to know the sum of the starting index, I must know
when `maxendinghere` is added from zero with the integers of my `iterable` list. However, when 
maxendinghere will always be zero to zero if it is less than and is updated even if the next continuous
sum (may not be the largest sum) is being summed up.

---

Is there a way to find the starting index of my maximum continuous summation index

```
from random import randrange
iterable = [randrange(-10,10) for r in xrange(100)]

def max_continuous_sequence(iterable):
    maxsum, maxendinghere = 0, 0
    index_pairs = [0,0]
    for i,x in enumerate(iterable):
        # summing next numbers
        maxendinghere += x
        if maxsum < maxendinghere:
            # found a higher sum
            maxsum = maxendinghere
            index_pairs[1] = i
        elif maxendinghere < 0:
            # resets the max here if next element is less than zero
            maxendinghere = 0
            # starts off the index at where we ended last
            index_pairs[0] = i+1
    return (index_pairs[0],index_pairs[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse the order of the elements, run your algorithm to compute the last index (which is really the first index of the initial sequence), and then compute how far it is from the end of the sequence to get the answer. Addition is commutative :)